# How to measure spectral irradiance vs wavelength for sunlight?

Tags: optics, spectroscopy, experimental-technique, solar-cells, photonics

I am currently working on a project where I need to measure the spectral irradiance over a submerged solar panel at different depths of water. But I do not really know what can be used to measure it. A pyranometer can only measure the absolute irradiance but will not show the distribution with wavelength.
I need a similar graph:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You get yourself a spectrophotometer to analyze the absorption of the water sample and then you multiply that (corrected for the thickness) with the known solar spectrum. It may not be a cheap instrument to own, but there should be plenty of commercial labs offering such services that can do the testing for you if you only need it done a few times.

Comment: I am eating my words... there are cheap far-East instruments for less than $400 now. Makes me almost want to buy one, just for the fun of it to see how much precision such a box has. Wow. I am used to cheap electronics but I didn't think that now we can also buy cheap analytical instruments. Amazing.